# Antagonistically quoting someone`

Tags: discussion

This is more information for moderators, than a question.

I am going to start marking comments that directly quote what I said elsewhere, or allude pointlessly to previous arguments, with the obvious intention of needling me, as offensive.

So if you read these things, they may not appear to be personal attacks, but the most certainly are.

The behavior is as offensive as it is childish.  And the statements were true of the thing I said them about, but are demonstrably not true of the things they are being used to insult.  It is simply punishment for ever having seriously criticized the individual who considers themselves special.

This person has now decided to ensure my experience here is uniformly unpleasant.  He needs to be addressed in some way that actually works, eventually.  Vindictiveness is not 'nice', and is an obvious violation of our local standards.

I am going to keep complaining about each and every one of his actions against me until someone tells me what is being done to stop this.

I have basically been ordered not to defend myself, but I am not being defended by anyone else.  So I am going back to defending myself.

Comment: Please don't accept the idea that you have to take abuse quietly! On the contrary it's really important for the foundations of this community that we treat others with courtesy and respect...

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy when comments are removed, that has a reason. You don't need to put them back. If you disagree or don't understand why they were removed, ask a new meta question about it.

Comment: hope this wasn't me :/

Answer (score 7):

> I have basically been ordered not to defend myself, but I am not being defended by anyone else. So I am going back to defending myself.

That's not how things work on Stack Exchange. As our [Be Nice policy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) states:

> **Harassment and
>   bullying.** If you see a hostile interaction, [flag](/help/flagging) it. 
>   If it keeps up, *disengage* — we'll handle it. If something needs *staff* attention, you can use the [contact us](/contact) link at the bottom of every page.

If you have flagged and you *still* don't feel as if you are being protected from harassment and other sorts of abuse, feel free to contact the [Community team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do) and we can help mediate.

---

I should point out that responding to rude comments in kind makes moderation *substantially more complicated*. If one user continually goads another and the victim refuses to engage but just flags, it's really easy for the moderators to suspend the abusive user. But if *both* users trade insults, it just doesn't matter who instigated or who is in the right. As a moderator, I'm inclined to suspend both users and hope they learn to moderate their behavior when they return. (As a parent, I do the same thing when my twins get into a fight.)

Notice that leaving comments to "defend" yourself is never effective in terms of *stopping* the abuse. But a suspension *does* stop the abuse for as long as the user is blocked from commenting on the site. And moderators tend to be quick to re-up suspensions if the user continues their abusive behavior on their return. But it doesn't do you much good if you are also suspended.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some behaviour of that kind recently, and I tend to defend myself; I'd rather that comments were taken as they were originally planned to be as a means of asking clarification, or adding more useful information.

I'd suggest that if comments are used to do this then it will get to the point where perfectly innocuous comments asking for clarification will be seen as 'needling' - which is annoying.