# Bringing something to the moderator's attention

Tags: support

If it were the case that there was a specific user of this site who has had a long career in public forums of spreading aggressive and unapologetic anti semitism, including but in no way being limited to running multiple propagandist websites spreading literal Nazi rhetoric and libeling one of the most famous holocaust survivors, if it were the case that this user existed and they happened to also consistently post provocative and deceptive questions and answers on this site with the intent to push their hateful narrative, if all of this were the case how would I contact the moderators to make them aware of my grievances towards this users blatant attempts to make this website an outlet for their hate-speech?

Comment: Report it to SE directly if it is quite that bad, but you could raise a flag on any post of the users and provide an explanation of the problem

Comment: @JosephWeissman am I incorrect or didn't there use to be something at the bottom of every page that said "contact moderators"? The contact button that is there now takes you to contacting the help center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer is to be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104375/what-is-the-best-way-to-contact-a-moderator-about-a-user):

> - Flag one of his posts for a moderator, and explain.
> - Email team@stackoverflow.com

If this problem is sensitive and needs some explanatory context etc., a third option that may work here (since moderation is not that stressful on this site) is asking in a chat (Symposium or elsewhere) for some direct chat. I have done that before, inviting to a private chatroom. These are only accessible for the users explicitly allowed and (all) moderators.

Comment: I think that it needs explanatory context. I submitted a detailed ticket [here](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) two days ago, I received an email saying that I have ticket number 27356. I don't know if that goes to you guys or to the mods of SE in general, or something else. If that didn't end up going to you guys I can start a chatroom.

Comment: @Not_Here: Since this goes to the community management team of StackExchange and we are not involved until they approach us, I would say that if the danger is not imminent and it is necessary for one of us to know just in case, you should stick to the process already put into motion. If you deem it necessary that we/one of us know(s) ASAP, the chat is probably the more suitable option.

Comment: Unfortunately [only moderators can make private chatrooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184130/how-do-i-make-a-private-chat-room). Would it be possible for you to make one with me? I can make a gallery chatroom where only people I invite can talk but everyone can see it and I would rather have discretion in play.

Answer (score 1):

Jon Ericson provided a good answer on what to do noting that things can become complicated if there is engagement on the part of the one feeling offended: https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3332/29944

> I should point out that responding to rude comments in kind makes moderation substantially more complicated. If one user continually goads another and the victim refuses to engage but just flags, it's really easy for the moderators to suspend the abusive user. But if both users trade insults, it just doesn't matter who instigated or who is in the right.

Here's a quote from the code of conduct page which provides examples of what count as inappropriate conduct and how to report it: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/conduct

> **No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language.**
>   Even if you don’t intend it, this can have a negative impact on others.
>
> **No name-calling or personal attacks.**
>   Focus on the content, not the person. This includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to content (e.g. “lazy”).
>
> **No bigotry.**
>   We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples. When in doubt, just don’t.
>
> **No harassment.**
>   This includes, but isn’t limited to: bullying, intimidation, vulgar language, direct or indirect threats, sexually suggestive remarks, patterns of inappropriate social contact, and sustained disruptions of discussion.

Note that a flag may be raised for what might not be considered out-right "hate speech".

Raising a flag allows the user to address this issue effectively without becoming directly involved.

Comment: This is all useful and correct information in and of itself but it doesn't address the problem that I am facing. As I said in a comment above, I swear I remember there used to be a button that allowed you to directly message the moderators of each SE. Flagging posts isn't enough to handle this problem, I need to have an actual conversation with the moderators. I.e., as I stated, "how would I contact the moderators to make them aware". Flagging specific posts doesn't allow for a transparent enough exchange.